# Кеширование запросов PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, кэширование

Есть таблица в постгресе. Данные записываются туда редко, но читается часто. Возникла идея закэшировать результаты. Есть ли возможность это сделать в постгресе или в питоне, который и читает эти данные?

Comment: Я может не понимаю, но что вы собрались кешировать и зачем?)

Comment: Я собрался закешировать те самые результаты из таблицы, что постоянно базу не дергать, а прочитать из кеша.

Comment: Ну так сохраните результат запроса в csv'шке и читайте ее

Comment: А как проверять, изменилась база или нет? Получается, опять нужно базу прочитать, а так весь смысл теряется.

Comment: Дык при каждой записи перезаписывайте csv'шку.

Comment: Черт. Точно. Спасибо)

Comment: А еще вы не сказали какие у вас процессы питона. Если они долгоживущие, т.е. обслуживающие много запросов, а не один конкретный, после которого они завершаются, то можно кешировать прямо в памяти процесса.  Если же надо разнести кеш на множество процессов и возможно короткоживущих, то хорошим решением может стать использование memcached или redis

Comment: @Mike Очень долгоживущий. Это сайт на Flask